# What is the foreign key in a one-to-many self join in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an `Institution` model, where an Institution can belong to a `Parent Institution` and I'm setting this up as a self-join on the `institutions` table.

I'm using `sequelize` to set this up on postgres and the docs talk about how to set a self-join for a many-to-many association, but my model uses a one-to-many self-join (i.e. a parent Institution can have many children, but a child institution can only belong to 1 parent).

This is my model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Institution = sequelize.define(
    'Institution',
    {
      /* ... */

      parentId: DataTypes.INTEGER,

      /* ... */
    },
    {}
  )
  Institution.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Institution.belongsTo(Institution, {
      foreignKey: 'institutionId',
      as: 'parent',
    })
  }
  return Institution
}
```

What I'm not sure about is what to put as the `foreignKey` in the association above - should it be `institutionId` as I've put it now (i.e. with the `as: parent` parameter) or should it be `parentId`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be **parentId** because this field is a reference to a parent Institution

Comment: This worked! Thanks! For anyone wondering how to query it, it's `Institution.findAll( { include: [ { model: Institution, as: 'parent' } ] } )`